# Як перекласти з російської заклик "(Думай) про себя!" (у сенсі "мовчки")?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти з російської заклик *"(Думай) про себя!"* (у сенсі "мовчки")? Дякую.

UPDATE. Уточнюю:

1. *"Сиди мовчки!"* - грубо.
2. Російською можна сказати *"Читай про себя"*, *"Думай про себя"*, *"Решай в уме"*, а не просто *"Чуть потише"* - бо останнє не таке конкретне.
   Як сказати українською? Зрозуміло, що *"Читай про себе"*, *"Думай про себе"*, *"Розв'язуй в розумі"* не підійдуть.

Comment: Тобто "*думай мовчки*" вас не влаштовує?

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language.SE. Будь ласка, додайте до свого запитання що ви шукали і яких висновків ви вже дійшли. Почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Ви завжди можете виправити своє питання або відповідь за допомогою посилання [edit].

Comment: user3107513, Ваше запитання не виглядає повним щонайменше тому, що незромуміло, чим Вам не підходить Вами же запропонований варіант «мовчки»? Чи він влаштовує, але Ви просто хочете якісь альтернативні варіанти для розгляду? Чи все таки він не влаштовує, враховуючи Ваші особисті мету/контекст (тоді — які саме?)?

Comment: user3107513, тобто «думай мовчки» не підходить тому, що звучить занадто грубо — так?

Comment: user3107513, як щодо «думай не вголос [будь ласка]»? (Теж три слова і явно не грубо.)

Comment: Досить добре. Але у "читай не в голос" - деяке протиріччя, ви не вбачаєте?

Comment: @user3107513, тільки «[вголос](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7021&page=258)» разом пишеться. Ні, ніякого протиріччя не бачу (ІМХО, читати можна вголос і подумки). В чому воно?

Comment: Дякую. Може здалося. Що читають у першу чергу вголос - або зайве заперечення важко сприймається. "Подумки" - непогане слово.

Comment: @Kosarar, «„подумки“ — непогане слово» — це [Олегу Бутузову дякуйте](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1129/4). Я якось без нього не доклепав (чи, може, воно мені здавалося тавтологією, тому відразу підсвідомо відкинув, а потім у нього побачив — і зрозумів, що непогано).

Answer (score 6):

Це все майже завше замінюється звичним словом [*мовчки*](http://sum.in.ua/s/movchky). Це не є чимось грубим, якщо хочете бути доволі ввічливим, то є допоміжне слово [*будь ласка*](http://sum.in.ua/s/laska) чи залучайте іншими ввічливими звертаннями, або ж не використовуйте тільки [наказовий спосіб дієслова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1) однини. Також слідкуйте за інтонацією, не ставте наголос на *мовчки*. Це як поставити наголос на *про себя*, що також буде доволі безтактно та грубо.

Приклади.

- *Будь ласка, сидіть мовчки.* *Доволі часто зустрічається серед процесу навчання, тощо.*
- *Мовчки думай.*
- *Будь ласка, мовчки.*

Є ще такий рідкий варіант, якщо контекст зрозумілий:

- *[Будь ласка,] без слів.*

---

[Варіант](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/1129#1129) *подумки* — доволі непоганий, але не так гарно заходить до зв'язку з деякими словами. Наприклад *думайте подумки*, *читайте подумки* , типу це як *у думках читати* чи щось [*уявне*](http://sum.in.ua/s/ujavnyj), тощо. Але *рахувати подумки* цілком можливо. Це дещо підтверджується сервісом [mova.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx?l1=209).

На жаль, не дається пряма лінка до прикладів, але варіант заповнювання чи результат можете побачити на зображенні:

[image: Приклади]

---

Якщо не у контексті прохання, то можна використовувати [*безмовно*](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezmovno). Приклади:

- *Сидіти безмовно*
- *Безмовно читав*
- *Безмовно звелів*

Comment: Будь ласка, поправте посилання на mova.info. Якщо сайт не надає можливості прямих посилань, то спробуйте зробити **screenshot** або пошукати **інший** словник, де пряме посилання можливе.

Comment: Дякую, що додали зображення, але ж воно величезне вийшло. І більша частина змісту картинки зовсім не виглядає, як підтвердження до слів «дещо підтверджується сервісом mova.info.» У моєму розумінні, скріншот просто показує що так, дійсно, існують приклади використання слова `подумки`. Але ж ви не це хотіли сказати?

Answer (score 5):

Можливо такий сталий вираз підійде:

> **Тихо будь!**

Вислів трошки відгонить діалектизмом, незвичністю, що додає йому певної цікавинки. Але як видно з наведеного прикладу використання, він використовується класиками. Зауважте, що дівчинка каже це ніжно, тобто, вислів сам по собі не грубощі.

> — Гаразд, заходь,— шепнула дівчинка. — Тільки *тихо будь!*
>   Вона впустила його до себе в серце, і він, згорнувшись там клубочком, висвистував смутненьку мелодію.
>   [Валерій Шевчук](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [*Панна квітів*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=9F73CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT157&lpg=PT157&dq=%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=YI-RJLh7l9&sig=tDIywf6rBtO8Yvj8PGyFagwsAto&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6yOfT8vDSAhWEdCwKHSvoClY4FBDoAQgrMAM#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C&f=false)

---

Хочу також підтримати варіант [запропонований Oleg Butuzov](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1132/9) - **думайте подумки**. Саме завдяки тавтології він звертає на себе увагу і заслуговує на те, щоб стати сталим виразом.

Comment: Загрубо та задіалектно. :(

Comment: У вашому прикладі класиків інший контекст - там буквально заклик (по-) бути тихо (нічого не роблячи, на відміну від моєго випадку).

Answer (score 2):

Правильний варіант — **[сам/сама] до себе**.

---

TL;DR: Я розглядаю запитання у максимально широкому змісті. Тобто, не лише у контексті прохання, а і у наступних прикладах:

> - <sub>англ.</sub> *And I think **to myself**, What a wonderful world!* — [Луї Армстронг](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_a_Wonderful_World)
> - <sub>рос.</sub> *Чёрт же меня дернул связаться с девчонкой, бормотал он **про себя*** — І.С. Тургенєв. «Бретёр»

СУМ пропонує одне із значень у статті [*сам*](http://sum.in.ua/s/sam):

г) ледве чутно; не в голос; подумки.

> *Отаке-то лихо тяжке,
>
>   Батьку ти мій, друже!
>
>   Блужу в снігах та сам собі:
>
>   «Ой не шуми, луже!»*
>   — Тарас Шевченко, I, 1963, 64;
>
> *В списку зарахованих до університету його не було.. — От і все. — сказав він сам собі*  — Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 58;

Словосполучення *«[сам] до себе»* часто використовується у п'єсах¹, коли герой думає одне, а говорить інше:

```
Д і к е о п о л ь: Ще одну лиш річ
    Прохаю в тебе: глечик дай надщерблений.
Е в р і п і д: Візьми і йди вже! Гість такий - то нудь одна.
Д і к е о п о л ь: (до себе) А сам він скільки люду міг занудити!
    Прошу востаннє, Евріпіде, милий мій, -
    Дай отой глечик, що заткнутий губкою.
```

— [Арістофан, «Ахарняни»](http://www.ae-lib.org.ua/texts/aristophanes__acharnians__ua.htm) у перекладі видатного українського перекладача [Андрія Содомори](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

---

Варто зауважити, що той же СУМ також пропонує і варіант **[сам/сама] про себе**. У статті [*себе*](http://sum.in.ua/s/sebe) читаємо:

а) ледве чутно.

> *[Руфін (до раба):] Веди [гостя] сюди, се ти не розібрав. (Раб іде, мимрячи щось тихо **про себе**)* (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 345);
>   *Проясніло [у Чумака] на душі, аж коли зустрівся з Ярошенком. Той, десь-то, мав добру розмову в повіткомі комнезаму, бо був веселий і намугикував **про себе**...* (Валентин Речмедін, Весняні грози, 1961, 68);

б) не вимовляючи вголос.

> *Голова в кожної схилилася; очі вниз потупились... Кожна щось думала **сама про себе**...* (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 291);
>   *«Чекайте, — весело думав **про себе** Маковей, — чекайте... Хіба це вже й край... Стану і я згодом таким воякою, як наші полкові чвовкю [розвідники]...»* (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 59);
>   *Мусив відзначити **про себе** Функе: новин багато буде на Україні. Недарма шість років вів ..баталії з польською шляхтою Хмельницький* (Натан Рибак, Переяславська Рада, 1953, 41);

Особисто мені другий варіант здається русизмом, але зважаючи на масовість використання, мушу додати його до відповіді.

---

¹ З очевидних причин, я не включав цитати із численних прикладів використання словосполучення *«[сам] до себе»* у творах Леся Подерв'янського ([один](http://www.doslidy.org.ua/stories/st-hamlet-new.htm), [два](http://doslidy.org.ua/stories/st-repka.htm)).

Comment: Це цікаво. Але «сам до себе» не обов'язково означає мовчки. В приблизно половині наведених Вами прикладів персонажі роблять це вголос, а не мовчки. Припустімо таку ситуацію: Іван щось мимрить сам до себе, але заважаючи іншим — і йому кажуть… що йому скажуть? невже «думай/читай/вирішуй сам до себе»? (він же й так це робить сам до себе.) мабуть, йому скажуть «думай не вголос»/«не говори вголос», а не «давай сам до себе».

Answer (score 0):

'Думай/Міркуй подумки' або 'Думати просебе' (особисто я вживав і вживаю другий варіант).

Comment: «Просебе» — хіба є таке слово?

Comment: я суржикомовний, нажаль, і тому міг спокійно сам того не вважаючи запозичити таку нісенітницю як "просебе" ну чи "про себе". Але це так як я говорив. Принаймні до сьогодні.

Comment: Але про «подумки» і особливо про заміну «думай» на «міркуй» (щоби уникнути тавтології «думай подумки») — хороші ідеї :).

Comment: @Sasha Може тавтологія тут якраз доречна. Щоб більше звернути увагу адресанта на звернення. Типу, креативчик:)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Цей допис сильно виграв би від доданих посилань, які б пояснювали, де і ким вживається запропоноване словосполучення, які воно має конотації чи обмеження вживання тощо. Без цього допис виглядає як суб'єктивна і нічим не підтверджена думка автора.

Answer (score 0):

Банальний варіант:

> Думати/читати/вирішувати не [вголос](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7021&page=258).

Comment: -1. Цей допис не пояснює валідності прикладу, а також правил вживання, і стаття за посиланням також не додає ясності. Окрім того, ключові тези звідти варто додавати до відповіді, щоб не було link-only answer.

Comment: @bytebuster, я вважаю, що така пропозиція не потребує додаткових пояснень, оскільки я пропоную не фразеологізм чи спеціальний вираз, а просто застосувати «не» і «вголос» у їхніх прямих значеннях. Можливість такого застосування, по-моєму, не викликає сумнівів (хоча, може, конструкція не найкоротша/навлучніша). Але дякую за послідовність :).